# What different between init plugin use .each and just selector.initplugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, init

direct to topic.

people A use code to initial plugin like this:

```
 $(".whatever").each(function(){
   $(this).initplugin;
   // blah blah blah... stuff
})
```

and people B use code to initial plugin like this:

```
$(".else").initplugin();
```

so, what is the difference in the above code?
in memory usage,
in simple usage,
or what your reason..

im sorry im newbie in JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both has the same result.  If you need to have some condition , lets say you want to exclude the plugin for just one of the items with the same class, then the first option will be better as you can wrap code around it:

```
$(".whatever").each(function()
{
    if(somecondition)
    {  
       $(this).initplugin;
    }

   // blah blah blah... stuff
});
```

Otherwise applying the plugin by class selector will be fine.

```
$(".else").initplugin();
```

As for performance, There should not be that big a difference as your using JQuery for both

The .each function simply does this:

```
function (obj, callback, args) {
var value, i = 0,
    length = obj.length,
    isArray = isArraylike(obj);

if (args) {
    if (isArray) {
        for (; i < length; i++) {
            value = callback.apply(obj[i], args);

            if (value === false) {
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (i in obj) {
            value = callback.apply(obj[i], args);

            if (value === false) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // A special, fast, case for the most common use of each
} else {
    if (isArray) {
        for (; i < length; i++) {
            value = callback.call(obj[i], i, obj[i]);

            if (value === false) {
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (i in obj) {
            value = callback.call(obj[i], i, obj[i]);

            if (value === false) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

return obj;
}
```

Taken from: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=2.0.3&fn=jQuery.each.

As for applying the plugin to per class in the second case I am not 100% sure what happens under the hood there but its still JQuery and be assured JQuery will always be slower than using raw JavaScript

Comment: I have tried it on Intel Celeron processor and it makes the fan turns on earlier when running multiple .each

who knows, maybe my observations are wrong. but thanks for the answer, mr loanburger? :D

Comment: No worries pal.  Please accept or up-vote up my answer if it assisted you in any way.

Comment: okay, i cant up-vote.. my reputation is to down... i just accept your answer.. thnks..